# Why is Matlab's cluster method able to accept only two inputs? What does it mean when it does? Ex: clusterX = cluster(gmfit,X);

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Matlab's cluster method documentation says cluster takes in 3 arguments:

T = cluster(Z,'Cutoff',C)

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cluster.html

But line 56 inside the cluster function seems to prohibit having only two variables for varagin:

'''matlab
if nargin < 2

error(message('stats:cluster:TooFewInputs'));

end
'''

Why is this code fence formatting failing?

Anyway, I interpret the above test with nargin<2 as you need Z as an input and then on top of that, at least two arguments (at least 3 total)?

**However, in the Gaussian Mixture Model tutorial, cluster() seems to take in only two arguments and it runs fine. Why is cluster() able to take only two arguments, and what is it doing in the below case?**

Example:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clustering-using-gaussian-mixture-models.html

[image]

I assumed that the cluster method for this

Answer (score 1):

> Anyway, I interpret the above test with nargin<2 as you need Z as an
>   input and then on top of that, at least two arguments (at least 3
>   total)?

`nargin` is the number of all arguments; not restricted to `varargin`. So, `cluster` function can take two or more arguments. GMM usage is therefore valid.

Answer (score 1):

That documentation only explains how to

> Construct agglomerative clusters from linkages

For which you do need three parameters.

It does not explain GMM.